# How to get Commerce price without any adjustments

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to show "Buy for XX USD more and get free shipping", I know how to get `$cart->get('total_price')->getValue()[0]['number']` but it is including any adjustments including shipment, I need just price of all items in a cart without any adjustments.

Using devel I found out that shipment value is stored in `$cart->get('adjustments')->getValue()[0]['value']`, but I don't know how to get to protected `amount->number` (see picture), any help? ) MY variable `$PriceWithoutAdjustments = $cart->get('adjustments')->getValue()[0]['value'];`)

Or even better, how to get price without adjustments?

Many thanks[image: DSM]

Comment: try `$priceWithoutAdjustments->getAmount()`

Comment: @johnSmith, thanks!, almost there.. just need to get number value, `$PriceWithoutAdjustments->getAmount()['number']` is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot work with those classes like with drupal´s fieldable entities

There is this nice little hint in your debug output that shows which class is used
e.g

[Drupal\commerce_order\Adjustment](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/643bb39620c083f6d52acd41c8170d7f34b40e1c/modules/order/src/Adjustment.php)

So i dont know commerce plugin but i can look into the source, i just searched for the classes in the [online available source-code](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/tree/643bb39620c083f6d52acd41c8170d7f34b40e1c)

and see that Adjustment has the method `getAmount`

```
$priceWithoutAdjustments->getAmount();
```

which will return of type [Drupal\commerce_price\Price](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/643bb39620c083f6d52acd41c8170d7f34b40e1c/modules/price/src/Price.php)

which has a method `->getNumber()`

which seems to be what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks! That's it! Finally I understood.. Many thanks.

Comment: Youre welcome, please mark this as answer then